# Return zero for time slot if data is not present

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get data for a period of two minutes every minute there should be data for each second for mid,sid,pid combination. if data is not present for a second for each combination it should return IC value as zero.For two minutes there will be 120 time slots if data is not present for mid,sid, pid combination for any time slot it should return zero.This data is used to plot line chart if data is not present it should go down to zero.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DeviceData](
[Id] [BIGINT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MId] [INT] NOT NULL,
[SId] [INT] NOT NULL,
[PId] [INT] NOT NULL,
[DataTime] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
[IC] [INT] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DeviceData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)

 SELECT  [MId] ,
    [SId] ,
    [PId] ,
    [DataTime] ,
    SUM([IC]) AS Value
 FROM    [DeviceData]
 WHERE   DataTime BETWEEN DATEADD(MINUTE, -2, GETUTCDATE())
             AND     GETUTCDATE()
 GROUP BY [MId] ,
    SID ,
    PId ,
    [DataTime];
```

Comment: Create a help table that stores the values 0 - 120. outer join.

Comment: This is more complicated than it sounds.  What happens when you have data with a fractional second?  Or data that is at xx:xx:00:00 and xx:xx:00.999?

Comment: This is real time data, Time slots will differ if a table is created each time it should be recreated, So worried about performance, There is not need to consider fraction of second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a numbers CTE:

```
with Numbers as
(
select 1 as NN
union all
select NN+1
from Numbers
where NN < 120
)
, Times as
(
select dateadd(ss, 
               NN, 
               DATEADD(MINUTE, 
                       -2, 
                       dateadd(ms, 
                               -datepart(ms, 
                                        GETUTCDATE()),
                               GETUTCDATE()) ) as Timeslot
from Numbers
)
select Timeslot, DD.*
from Times
left join DeviceData DD
  on Timeslot = dateadd(ms, -datepart(ms, GETUTCDATE()),GETUTCDATE())
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000) -- This will bypass the recursion error
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I got this error "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Comment: @shijithmc `maxrecursion` defaults to 100, overcome this by using the option as above

Comment: Thanks its solved, But this does't return mid,sid or pid